# QVector<int> with initializer list fails with 3 items

Tags: c++, qt, initializer-list, qabstractitemmodel

In a custom item model, I want to call data changed with some given roles.

With 2 items in the `initializer-list`, it compiles just fine:

```
emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>{ Qt::CheckStateRole, Qt::DisplayRole });
```

However, when I add a third item to the list it fails:

```
emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int> { Qt::CheckStateRole, Qt::DisplayRole, Qt::DecorationRole });

error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'QVector<int>' 
2>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

It doesn't seem to matter what the roles are, any two will compile and the third will not. I'm using MSVC2013 and Qt 5.4.1. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already, I would update your VS2013 to Update 5. Especially, in [Update 4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2994375) they have fixed some issues with initializer lists. Also see this [QTBUG-39142](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39142)

It seems like your compiler is trying to construct a `QVector` object using the normal constructors. You could also verify that you have C++11 enabled and `Q_COMPILER_INITIALIZER_LISTS` is defined.